# Python: If file does not end with , move up the line below

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a csv file which is created from a program as a report.  This file has lines in it that are not correctly split, all of there lines should end with **,\n** What I want to do is if the line does not end with a **,\n** the script should move the line from below to the line that is missing , to up
this is how I have tried so far

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as data, open('output.csv','w') as output:                          
    for line in data:
        if not line.endswith(',\n'):
        line = line.rstrip()
    output.write(line)`
```

but this is not working in below case:

```
name, address, pincode,
amruta, peth, 41578,
ashwini,'peth, 
MH', 415407,
akshay, sangli, 
478595,
```

Output should be

```
name, address, pincode,
amruta, peth, 41578,
ashwini,'peth,MH', 415407,
akshay, sangli, 478595,
```

Output i am getting

```
name, address, pincode,
amruta, peth, 41578,
ashwini,'peth,
MH', 415407,
akshay, sangli, 478595,
```

Comment: `perl -0777 -pe 's/,\n/,/igs'`? Also, please fix your formatting: you're using single quotes (apostrophes) instead of backticks to delimit your code.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: two question:

1. Is your requirement to simply ignore the lines which doesnt have a , at the end?
2. In your sample csv not every line has 3 elements though the header shows 3 expected columns (name, address, pincode).. Should those also be ignored?

can you give what is the expected o/p for the above example and whats the o/p you are getting currently?

Comment: @Arun Kaliraja Baskaran
I have mentioned the output which I am looking for
if you will see 3rd line, 'peth, MH' is separated by  comma and i want to third line to be **ashwini,'peth,MH', 415407,**

Comment: your question and solution are very contradictory.. your question says " is if the line does not end with a ,\n the script should move the line from below to the line that is missing" but in the example you have given, you are trying to merge lines 4 and 5 even though line 4 ends with ,\n..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for the lines:

```
ashwini,'peth,
MH', 415407,
```

The upper line does, in fact, en with '**,**', so it does work "as intended".

So, instead, you could work with the column size expected. The following code solves your problem:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as data, open('output.txt','w') as output:
    bad_size = False
    bad_line = None
    for line in data:
        columns = line.split(',')
        
        if (len(columns) - 1) < 3:
            if bad_size:
                line = bad_line.rstrip('\n') + line
                bad_size = False
            else:
                bad_size = True
                bad_line = line
        if not bad_size:
          output.write(line)
```